# Show that $e^{-x}/\sqrt{1-2x} \leq e^{2x^2}$

Tags: inequality

Show that for all $x$ in some interval nonempty interval, (and find the interval):
$$\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{1-2x}} \leq e^{2x^2}$$

My first attempt was to use the bound I know that looks similar here: $1+x \leq e^x$ giving me:

$$e^{2x^2} \geq 1+2x^2$$

but I'm not sure how to find an interval that makes the desired inequality true.

Comment: Do you have to find the biggest interval possible?

Comment: Can you see that it definitely holds for $x\leq 0$? Can you see that it remains to consider $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: I would be happy with any interval

Comment: If you’re happy with any interval, then just take $\{0\}$.